# create infinite animation in tween.js

Tags: javascript, animation, tween.js

I am creating an animation for a sphere moving along all the vertices of a line. I have this code:

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
var duration = 100;
// Iterate through each vertex in the line, starting at 1.
for (var i = 1, len = vertices.length; i < len; i++) {
 // Set the position of the sphere to the previous vertex.
    sphere.position.copy(vertices[i - 1]);
 // Create the tween from the current sphere position to the current vertex.
    new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.position).to(vertices[i], duration).delay(i * duration).start();

}
```

How I can do to make when the sphere is on the last vertex, the field start over again animation.

Comment: You could make two seperate for loops, both in functions, one which goes from start to end, the other which goes from end to start, and in both for loops start the other for loop when you're on the last iteration. 
If you don't want it to go from start to end and back, you could call the start to end function again after it's last iteration as well.

Comment: @leroydev thanks for responding, but how I can do that ?. how I can do that when the animation is ended, is again a function call or something that makes the cycle start again infinitely ?.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [repeat](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#repeat), as explained in the official documentation, which you should probably give a detailed read-through to see if it has examples that cover setting up multiple tweens and then running them on repeat.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans with repeat('infinity') not works. Besides, all this within a cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a private chat with yavg, and the following solution works:

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
var duration = 10;

function startToEnd() {
  var i = 0;
  async.eachSeries(vertices, function(vertice, callback) {
    if (i !== 0) {
      sphere.position.copy(vertices[i - 1]);
      new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.position).to(vertices[i], duration).delay(duration).onComplete(function() {
        callback(null);
      }).start();
    } else {
      callback(null);
    }
    i++;
  }, startToEnd);
}
startToEnd();
```

It'll Tween from the start vertix to the end vertix and repeat this process infinitely. It does use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) though, to ease implementing Tweening from one vertix to the other for me.

Comment: thank you...more or less I understand what you explained to me ..
but does not work, I get this error: "TypeError: Can not read property 'x' of undefined
     at THREE.Vector3.copy (three.min.js: 37)
     at drawSphere (script.js: 519)
     at endToStart (script.js: 532)
     at startToEnd (script.js: 527) "

Comment: I don't know the details about the rest of your script nor am I familiar with the libraries you're using but I did loop down to 0 while you were looping from 1, I fixed it now, maybe it fixes your problem. (depends on whether the first vertice is different from the rest)

Comment: thank you very much you are very kind. Now the problem is that not load the website crashes. :(

Comment: this may help: tween has a function called .onComplete (). This is triggered when the animation ends.

tween.onCompleteCallback (doSomething);

function doSomething () {
// ...
}

Comment: I updated my answer, I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish now and I added usage of onComplete. I still can't test it out though since I don't have the entire script.

Comment: Thank you so much. this line fails, because no defined above "tweenToStart" ("ReferenceError: tweenToStart is not defined")

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, that was an old name I used, fixed it.

Comment: If you want more help, provide the code that's needed to run this. I won't be able to help you if I only have access to this small part of the code. Also, it would be useful for me if you'd describe how you want it to work. (For example: the sphere going from start to end and the other way around endlessly, on the same tempo)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98018/discussion-between-yavg-and-leroydev).